# Setting label text with jQuery fails to affect what is displayed

Tags: jquery, razor, label

Well...you've seen this question before...thought this was easy.

I have :
VS 2013 Pro
MVC 5.2.2 
Razor 3.2.2
Bootstrap 3.2.0
JQuery 2.1.1
jQuery UI 1.11.1
MS jQuery Unobtrusive Ajax 3.2.2
Modernizer 2.8.3
Respond 1.4.2

And Kendo MVC v2014.2.716 - but that *shouldn't* matter as I'm just trying to affect a label.

I have a view which shows many fields, but the label in question is in a partial view. I know, I know - "why do you use a partial view?!?!" - Never mind, everything else works. If you can prove *why* what I want to do will fail specifically because of using a partial view, then I'll change it.

All I am trying to do is update a label's text with jQuery

In the view to load the partial view:

```
        @{ var vddAddress = new ViewDataDictionary(ViewData) { TemplateInfo = new TemplateInfo() { HtmlFieldPrefix = "Address" } };}
        @Html.Partial("_AddressPartial", Model.Address, @vddAddress)
```

ok - in my partial view I display an address:

of all the fields, the two that are important are:

```
   <div class="row">
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.State, new { @class = "control-label col-sm-2 col-md-2 col-lg-2", id = "lbl_Address_State" })
    <div class="col-sm-4 col-md-4 col-lg-4">
        @(Html.Kendo().ComboBoxFor(model => model.State)
        .Placeholder("Select Province...")
        .DataTextField("Text")
        .DataValueField("Text")
        .Suggest(true)
        .BindTo(Model.Provinces)
        .HtmlAttributes(new { style = "width:100%" })
        )

        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.State)
    </div>
</div>


<div class="row">
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.MailCode, new { @class = "control-label col-sm-2 col-md-2 col-lg-2", id = "lbl_Address_MailCode" })
    <div class="col-sm-4 col-md-4 col-lg-4">
        @(Html.Kendo().ComboBoxFor(model => model.MailCode)
        .Placeholder("Select Postal...")
        .DataTextField("Text")
        .DataValueField("Text")
        .Suggest(true)
        .BindTo(Model.MailCodes)
        )
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.MailCode)
    </div>
</div>
```

When this first shows up, from the model, the label displays :

Province/State

When my geo information loads and my Country Kendo ComboBox is databound, the databound event fires and in that javascript function, I try to set the label text.

a la :

```
<script type="text/javascript">

function onCountryDataBound() {
    var ddlCountry = $("#Address_Country").data("kendoComboBox");
    if (ddlCountry.selectedIndex == 1) {
        $('#lbl_Address_State').val("Province");
        $('#lbl_Address_MailCode').val("Postal Code");

    } else {
        $('#lbl_Address_State').val("State");
        $('#lbl_Address_MailCode').val("Zip");

    }
};
```

While I follow along in debug...

The selectedIndex = -1 so after the call to :
       $('#lbl_Address_State').val("State");

I see...

```
    $('#lbl_Address_State')[0].innerHTML    "Province/State"    String
    $('#lbl_Address_State').val()   "State" String
    $('#lbl_Address_State') {...}   Object, (n)
        __proto__   {...}   Object, (n)
        context {...}   [Object, HTMLDocument]
        length  1   Number
        selector    "#lbl_Address_State"    String
        [0] {...}   [Object, HTMLLabelElement]
```

See that the innerHtml, that will display on the web page, is still "Province/State"

Note this is before $(document).ready(function () {

so..  being curious...when document ready comes along I call:

```
  $(document).ready(function () {

    var ddlCountry = $("#Address_Country").data("kendoComboBox");
    if (ddlCountry.selectedIndex == 1) {
        $('#lbl_Address_State').val("Province");
        $('#lbl_Address_MailCode').val("Postal Code");

    } else {
        $('#lbl_Address_State').val("State");
        $('#lbl_Address_MailCode').val("Zip");

    }
});
```

well, going through debug there shows that nothing changes...

```
        $('#lbl_Address_State').val()   "State" String
```

and

```
        $('#lbl_Address_State')[0].innerHTML    "Province/State"    String
```

both are still the same...

So the page continues to load and the original model Display text is still there...

Any idea how to affect change on the label text?

Comment: If you show the output HTML (of the rendered page), it is then far easier to spot issues with the jQuery (if any). It takes too long to mock up a project with all those specific addins.

Comment: good point. I might end up taking this one down. I solved this by setting the value via   $('#lbl_Address_State')[0].innerHTML = "new value"; instead of just $('#lbl_Address_State').val("new value"); It's just frustrating that the jQuery function - that normally works - didn't work in this case.